# Not defined object

Tags: javascript, class, object, constructor

I'm trying to get my object to print wolverine's email and name in the console. However, wolverine is showing up in the console as "not defined". How is this possible when it's a part of a class called new User? Any help would be appreciated.

```
class User {
  constructor(email, name) {
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
let userOne = new User('wolverine@marvel.com', wolverine);
let userTwo = new User('sabertooth@marvel.com', sabertooth);

console.log(userOne);
console.log(userTwo);
```

Comment: Need to enclose them in quotes, if you meant to use as strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `undefined` (or, in strict mode, an error) because the variables `wolverine` and `sabertooth` aren't assigned, so their value is... undefined.

You are probably looking to pass the names as strings too:

```
let userOne = new User('wolverine@marvel.com', 'wolverine');
let userTwo = new User('sabertooth@marvel.com', 'sabertooth');
```

Alternatively, you may be looking to have the names in variables first, then pass the variables in:

```
let nameOfGuyWithHandBlades = 'wolverine';
let totallyATiger = 'sabertooth';
let userOne = new User('wolverine@marvel.com', nameOfGuyWithHandBlades);
let userTwo = new User('sabertooth@marvel.com', totallyATiger);
```

Comment: It seems user is using strict mode there it will throw error `not defined`

Answer (score 1):

That is happening you are passing `wolverine` and `sabertooth` as variables, not as strings.

Correct usage:

```
let userOne = new User('wolverine@marvel.com', 'wolverine');
let userTwo = new User('sabertooth@marvel.com', 'sabertooth');
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing `wolverine` like that treats it as a variable, and it clearly can't find it.

If it's a string, like you did with the email, you need quotes `'`.

```js
let userOne = new User('wolverine@marvel.com', 'wolverine');
let userTwo = new User('sabertooth@marvel.com', 'sabertooth')
```

Comment: An "object" is a particular type in JavaScript – that's not quite related to this.

Comment: You're right, I changed with variable. Thanks :)